# Codepen JQuery Code Doesn't Work In My Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've searched online for a solution to this problem for a while now. Unfortunately, no luck. Here is the website I'm using the code from http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wagbYZ

Here is my code:

HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Cardo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>

    <body>

        <header class="main_h">

            <div class="row">
                <a class="logo" href="#">L/F</a>

                <div class="mobile-toggle">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>

                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=".sec01">Section 01</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".sec02">Section 02</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".sec03">Section 03</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".sec04">Section 04</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </div> <!-- / row -->

        </header>

        <div class="hero">

            <h1><span>loser friendly</span><br>Batman nav.</h1>

            <div class="mouse">
                <span></span>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row content">
            <h1 class="sec01">Section 01</h1>
            <p>Hello World!</p>
            <h1 class="sec02">Section 02</h1>
            <p>Hello World!</p>
            <h1 class="sec03">Section 03</h1>
            <p>Hello World!</p>
            <h1 class="sec04">Section 04</h1>
            <p>Hello World!</p>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
@mixin small {
  @media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
    @content;
  }
}


$color: #8f8f8f;
$color2: #e8f380;


.main_h {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  max-height: 70px;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 17px;
  background: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
  top: -100px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  @include small {
    padding-top: 25px;
  }
}

.open-nav {
  max-height: 400px !important;
  .mobile-toggle {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}

.sticky {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.93);
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lighten($color, 30%);
}

.logo {
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: $color;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  @include small {
    float: none;
  }
}

nav {
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
  @include small {
    width: 100%;
  }

  ul {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;
    float: right;
    @include small {
      padding-top: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 22px;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
    }

    li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 35px;
      line-height: 1.5;
      @include small {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 7px 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
    }
    a {
      color: #888888;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  }
}

.mobile-toggle {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 22px;
  top: 0;
  width: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  @include small {
    display: block;
  }

  span {
    width: 30px;
    height: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    border-radius: 1000px;
    background: $color;
    display: block;
  }
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 2%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  color: $color;
  background: white;
  font-family: "Cardo", serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 2;
}

.content {
  padding: 50px 2% 250px;
}

.hero {
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://srdjanpajdic.com/slike/2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 110px;
  min-height: 500px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;

  h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 1.3;

    span {
      font-size: 25px;
      color: $color2;
      border-bottom: 2px solid $color2;
      padding-bottom: 12px;
      line-height: 3;
    }
  }
}

.mouse {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 26px;
  height: 46px;
  border-radius: 13px;
  border: 2px solid $color2;
  bottom: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -14px;
  span {
    display: block;
    margin: 6px auto;
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: $color2;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-name: scroll;
    animation-name: scroll;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
}


@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(20px);
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.main_h').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
        $('.main_h').removeClass('sticky');
    }
});

$('.mobile-toggle').click(function() {
    if ($('.main_h').hasClass('open-nav')) {
        $('.main_h').removeClass('open-nav');
    } else {
        $('.main_h').addClass('open-nav');
    }
});

$('.main_h li a').click(function() {
    if ($('.main_h').hasClass('open-nav')) {
        $('.navigation').removeClass('open-nav');
        $('.main_h').removeClass('open-nav');
    }
});

$('nav a').click(function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    var offset = 70;
    var target = $(id).offset().top - offset;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target
    }, 500);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

The HTML and CSS work fine, but the JQuery is giving me problems.

Comment: Any error in console? Wrap code in `ready`

Comment: `ready` function may solve your issues or putting your javascript right before the `</body>` so the content has loaded.

Comment: "Giving me problems" is not a problem description.

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping the code in jquery document ready event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //event listeners
});
```